# Shadow Maps artifacts

Tags: xna, hlsl, shadow-mapping

We are working with XNA (Monogame) and currently trying to implement shadow maps. I believe that the topic of shadow maps issues has been already extensively covered on the Internet, however we can't quite match our particular problem to the existing solutions.

Below is a screenshot of the game:

[sever aliasing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvaxa.png)

On the left is a depth texture, on the right - our shadow maps applied. 
As you can see there are severe aliasing problems. We were considering making use of cascade shadow mapping at first, but then we realized it won't be helpful since the camera view (eye) has about the same Z distance to all the objects of the environment, thus, we cannot split the frustum into multiple subfrusta.

Below is the set up which yields no substantial aliasing:
[moderate aliasing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrKOL.png)

Which makes sense, since the farther the object from the light source, the more pixels get mapped to the same texel. In the latter case, the object is closer to the light source, which reduces the aliasing.

Increasing the resolution of the shadow map gives better results, but we were wondering whether there is another way to mitigate this problem.

We would greatly appreciate your help!

Cheers

Comment: Have you read the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416324(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: Yes, I did :) Perhaps I will go over it one more time.